# Node domination in constrained path search

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal, dijkstras-algorithm

It's possible to modify a graph search algorithm such as Dijkstra's or A* to allow for non-additive objectives or constraints. Is there a standard treatment for these algorithms to reduce unnecessary expansions?

For instance, consider a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$, with some edges colored red, and consider the problem of finding the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ which contains fewer than 3 red edges. This can be done by forming an augmented graph $G'=(V',E')$, where $V'=V\times\{0,1,2\}$ and $e'\in E'$ moves from $\langle a,i\rangle$ to $\langle b,i+1\rangle$ for red edges and to $\langle b,i\rangle$ for non-red-edges. That is, one duplicates the graph into three layers, with red edges moving up to the next layer and other edges staying on the same layer. Then one can find the shortest path in the augmented graph from $\langle s,0\rangle$ to any $\langle t,i\in\{0,1,2\}\rangle$, and that path is guaranteed to have fewer than three red edges.

All of which is straightforward, if manifestly inefficient (hence Constrained Shortest Paths being NP-hard). But some of this inefficiency seems needless. For instance, consider the case where two augmented vertices in the priority queue are $\langle v,0\rangle$ and $\langle v,2\rangle$ (for the same $v$ from the original graph). If the first vertex has a higher cost, it is necessary to expand both (because it may be the only way to avoid constraint violation later on), but if it has a lower cost, there's no reason to expand the second vertex: Any path through the second vertex will be no better than the equivalent path through the first vertex. But Dijkstra's Algorithm will continue expanding both fronts in the second case.

One could consider a similar case with more dimensions of constraint, such as also limiting the number of blue edge along a path. In that case, the "promising" augmented vertices from a given original vertex form a Pareto frontier, each one optimal for some relative weighting of objective and constraints.

Are there formal, well-known modifications to graph search algorithms (particularly A*) which support such a notion of partial domination, in order to eliminate unnecessary node expansions? Or, likewise, how it affects the definition of an admissible/consistent heuristic?